# Any way to associate a HtmlElement (.NET) to a JavaScript element?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make an extended version of a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) with stuff like highlighting text and getting properties or attributes of elements for a Web Scraper. `WebBrowser` functions doesn't help much at all, so if I could just find a way from `HtmlElement` to a JavaScript element (like the one returned by document.getElementById), and back, and then add JavaScript functions to the HTML from my application, it would make the job a lot easier. Right now I'm messing with the HTML of the code programmatically from C# and it's very messy. I was thinking about setting some unique Id to each HTML element from my program and then call the JavaScript `document.getElementById` to retrieve it. But that won't work, they might already have an Id assigned and I will mess up their HTML code. I don't know if I can give them some made up attribute like `my_very_own_that_i_hope_no_web_page_on_the_world_ever_uses_attribute` and then figure out if there is some JavaScript function `getElementByWhateveAttributeIWant` but I'm not sure if this would work. I read something about expansion or extended attributes on the DOM documentation in msdn but I'm not sure what that is about. Maybe some of you guys have a better way.

Comment: Ok what I'll try right now is to generate an unique Id for whatever elements doesn't have an Id by calling `System.Guid.NewGuid()`. Should work OK at least until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use some rendering engine like [trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) to get the data from html document. Here is the [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498651%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for trident/MSHTML. you can do google and can have samples in c#

Comment: I belive WebBrowser is a wrapper for that isn't it?

Comment: Oh Yeah ! But to a limited extent. If you use MSHTML you directly have the methods like GetElementBYId etc in c#.

Answer (score 0):

This is not nearly as hard as you imagine. You don't have to modify the document at all.

Once the `WebBrowser` has loaded a page, it's kept internally as a tree with the `document` node at the root. This node is available to your program, and you can find any element you want (or just enumerate them all) by walking the tree.

If you can give a concrete example, I can supply some code.